# Filter each column of a data.frame based on a specific value

Tags: r, dplyr

Consider the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(1:10,10,rep=TRUE)))

#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
#1   7  9  8  4 10
#2   2  4  9  4  9
#3   2  7  8  8  6
#4   8  9  6  6  4
#5   5  2  1  4  6
#6   8  2  2  1  7
#7   3  8  6  1  6
#8   3  8  5  9  8
#9   6  2  3 10  7
#10  2  7  4  2  9
```

Using `dplyr`, how can I filter, on each column (without implicitly naming them), for all values greater than 2.

Something that would mimic an hypothetical `filter_each(funs(. >= 2))`

Right now I'm doing:

```
df %>% filter(X1 >= 2, X2 >= 2, X3 >= 2, X4 >= 2, X5 >= 2)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
df %>% filter(!rowSums(. < 2))
```

Note: Let's say I wanted to filter only on the first 4 columns, I would do:

```
df %>% filter(X1 >= 2, X2 >= 2, X3 >= 2, X4 >= 2)
```

or

```
df %>% filter(!rowSums(.[-5] < 2))
```

Would there be a more efficient alternative ?

**Edit: sub question**

How to specify a column name and mimic an hypothethical `filter_each(funs(. >= 2), -X5)` ?

**Benchmark sub question**

Since I have to run this on a large dataset, I benchmarked the suggestions.

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(1:10,10e6,rep=TRUE)))

mbm <- microbenchmark(
Marat = df %>% filter(!rowSums(.[,!colnames(.) %in% "X5", drop = FALSE] < 2)),
Richard = filter_(df, .dots = lapply(names(df)[names(df) != "X5"], function(x, y) { call(">=", as.name(x), y) }, 2)),
Docendo = df %>% slice(which(!rowSums(select(., -matches("X5")) < 2L))),
times = 50
)
```

Here are the results:

```
#Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
#   Marat 1209.1235 1320.3233 1358.7994 1362.0590 1390.342 1448.458    50
# Richard 1151.7691 1196.3060 1222.9900 1216.3936 1256.191 1266.669    50
# Docendo  874.0247  933.1399  983.5435  985.3697 1026.901 1053.407    50
```

[image]

Comment: does it have to use dplyr?

Comment: Steven, I think you nailed it with `df %>% filter(!rowSums(. < 2))`

Comment: @MaratTalipov I guess, yes. But it would be convenient to be able to specify only the column *name* you do not want to filter on. Something like an hypothetical `filter_each(funs(. >= 2), -X5)`

Comment: Steven, it's not as elegant as your code, but you can try `df %>% filter(!rowSums(.[,!colnames(.)%in%'X5',drop=F] < 2))`

Comment: I agree with Marat and Richard. `rowSums()` looks good to me!

Comment: @MaratTalipov Yup. That's the only alternative I've found so far too. I'm under the impression my initial take on this wasn't that bad after all. Thanks !

Comment: @MaratTalipov I'll edit the original post to include the "column name instead of index" case. You can post your suggestion as the answer.

Comment: Can you explain why `df %>%  mutate(sum = rowSums(.) )` shows that each row sums to larger than 2, but your solution `df %>% filter(!rowSums(. < 2))` filters correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another option with `slice` which can be used similarly to `filter` in this case. Main difference is that you supply an integer vector to `slice` whereas `filter` takes a logical vector.

```
df %>% slice(which(!rowSums(select(., -matches("X5")) < 2L)))
```

What I like about this approach is that because we use `select` inside `rowSums` you can make use of all the special functions that `select` supplies, like `matches` for example.

---

Let's see how it compares to the other answers:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(1:10,10e6,rep=TRUE)))

mbm <- microbenchmark(
    Marat = df %>% filter(!rowSums(.[,!colnames(.) %in% "X5", drop = FALSE] < 2)),
    Richard = filter_(df, .dots = lapply(names(df)[names(df) != "X5"], function(x, y) { call(">=", as.name(x), y) }, 2)),
    dd_slice = df %>% slice(which(!rowSums(select(., -matches("X5")) < 2L))),
    times = 50L,
    unit = "relative"
)

#Unit: relative
#     expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#    Marat 1.304216 1.290695 1.290127 1.288473 1.290609    50
#  Richard 1.139796 1.146942 1.124295 1.159715 1.160689    50
# dd_slice 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    50
```

[image: pic]

**Edit note:** updated with more reliable benchmark with 50 repetitions (times = 50L).

---

Following a comment that base R would have the same speed as the `slice` approach (without specification of what base R approach is meant exactly), I decided to update my answer with a comparison to base R using almost the same approach as in my answer. For base R I used:

```
base = df[!rowSums(df[-5L] < 2L), ],
base_which = df[which(!rowSums(df[-5L] < 2L)), ]
```

Benchmark:

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(1:10,10e6,rep=TRUE)))

mbm <- microbenchmark(
  Marat = df %>% filter(!rowSums(.[,!colnames(.) %in% "X5", drop = FALSE] < 2)),
  Richard = filter_(df, .dots = lapply(names(df)[names(df) != "X5"], function(x, y) { call(">=", as.name(x), y) }, 2)),
  dd_slice = df %>% slice(which(!rowSums(select(., -matches("X5")) < 2L))),
  base = df[!rowSums(df[-5L] < 2L), ],
  base_which = df[which(!rowSums(df[-5L] < 2L)), ],
  times = 50L,
  unit = "relative"
)

#Unit: relative
#       expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#      Marat 1.265692 1.279057 1.298513 1.279167 1.203794    50
#    Richard 1.124045 1.160075 1.163240 1.169573 1.076267    50
#   dd_slice 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    50
#       base 2.784058 2.769062 2.710305 2.669699 2.576825    50
# base_which 1.458339 1.477679 1.451617 1.419686 1.412090    50
```

[image: pic2]

Not really any better or comparable performance with these two base R approaches.

**Edit note #2:** added benchmark with base R options.

Comment: This feels more natural, more `dplyr`-esque and is actually more efficient. Will update the benchmark in OP.

Comment: This is very crafty.  Nice answer

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel, really? I did the benchmark with base R and it was slower. Would be interested in seeing what you mean

Comment: @ actually I ran microbenchmark with my only solution so this lead to 1! You are correct!

Answer (score 6):

Here's an idea that makes it fairly simple to choose the names.  You can set up a list of calls to send to the `.dots` argument of `filter_()`.   First a function that creates an unevaluated call.

```
Call <- function(x, value, fun = ">=") call(fun, as.name(x), value)
```

Now we use `filter_()`, passing a list of calls into the `.dots` argument using `lapply()`, choosing any name and value you want.

```
nm <- names(df) != "X5"
filter_(df, .dots = lapply(names(df)[nm], Call, 2L))
#   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
# 1  6  5  7  3  1
# 2  8 10  3  6  5
# 3  5  7 10  2  5
# 4  3  4  2  9  9
# 5  8  3  5  6  2
# 6  9  3  4 10  9
# 7  2  9  7  9  8
```

You can have a look at the unevaluated calls created by `Call()`, for example `X4` and `X5`, with

```
lapply(names(df)[4:5], Call, 2L)
# [[1]]
# X4 >= 2L
#
# [[2]]
# X5 >= 2L
```

So if you adjust the `names()` in the `X` argument of `lapply()`, you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

> How to specify a column name and mimic an hypothethical filter_each(funs(. >= 2), -X5) ?

It might be not the most elegant solution, but it gets the job done:

```
df %>% filter(!rowSums(.[,!colnames(.)%in%'X5',drop=F] < 2))
```

In case of several excluded columns (e.g. X3,X5), one can use:

```
df %>% filter(!rowSums(.[,!colnames(.)%in%c('X3','X5'),drop=F] < 2))
```

Comment: It might be faster to use `names` instead of `colnames` since `names` is primitive

Answer (score 2):

If you only wanted to filter on the first four columns, as:

```
df %>% filter(X1 >= 2, X2 >= 2, X3 >= 2, X4 >= 2)
```

...try this:

```
df %>% 
  filter_at(vars(X1:X4), #<Select columns to filter
  all_vars(.>=2) )       #<Scope with all_vars (or any_vars)
```

An alternative is to exclude the columns you'd like to filter, as:

```
df %>% 
  filter_at(vars(-X5)), #<Exclude column X5
  all_vars(.>=2) )
```