# Filter specific column of a data.frame with also specific range

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to select rows of a data.frame using `filter()`. The condition to select a row is that at least one value out of five variables should be in an interval. I don't know how to apply such a condition.

I have checked similar issues and tried them but no luck!
for example 
[Filter each column of a data.frame based on a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183653/filter-each-column-of-a-data-frame-based-on-a-specific-value)

Here is a reproducible example:

```
  xx <- rep(rep(seq(0,800,200),each=10),times=2)
  yy<-replicate(5,c(replicate(2,sort(10^runif(10,-1,0),decreasing=TRUE)),replicate(2,sort(10^runif(10,-1,0),decreasing=TRUE)), replicate(2,sort(10^runif(10,-2,0),decreasing=TRUE)),replicate(2,sort(10^runif(10,-3,0),decreasing=TRUE)), replicate(2,sort(10^runif(10,-4,0), decreasing=TRUE))))

  V <- rep(seq(100,2500,length.out=10),times=2)
  No <- rep(1:10,each=10)
  df <- data.frame(V,xx,yy,No)
```

I want to filter `X1:X5` columns so that the row is selected if any value in X1 to X5 is in the (0.5;0.55) interval.

```
library(dplyr)

f_1 <- df%>%
filter(X1:X5>=0.5&X1:X5<=0.55)
```

I got error

```
    Warning messages:
1: In c(0.867315118241628, 0.720280300480341, 0.673805202395872, 0.489167242541468,  :
  numerical expression has 100 elements: only the first used
2: In c(0.867315118241628, 0.720280300480341, 0.673805202395872, 0.489167242541468,  :
  numerical expression has 100 elements: only the first used
3: In c(0.867315118241628, 0.720280300480341, 0.673805202395872, 0.489167242541468,  :
  numerical expression has 100 elements: only the first used
4: In c(0.867315118241628, 0.720280300480341, 0.673805202395872, 0.489167242541468,  :
  numerical expression has 100 elements: only the first used
```

Comment: what exactly is the condition you want filter to apply? For now, `X1:X5 >= 0.5 & X1:X5 <= 0.5` is equivalent to `X1:X5 == 0.5`

Comment: @scoa oh I am sorry. `X1:X5 >= 0.5 & X1:X5 <= 0.55` is fine.

Comment: so you just have to adapt the solution in the question you linked. Here with Marat's answer: `df%>%
  filter(rowSums(.[,names(.) %in% paste0("X",1:5)] >= 0.50 & .[,names(.) %in% paste0("X",1:5)] <= 0.55) == 5)` Note that this will likely return an empty data.frame since this is a very narrow window

Comment: @scoa Ok you can increase we can increase the window `<= 0.7`. however with the code you provide I'm getting error***

>[1] V  xx X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 No
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

Comment: I tried with a larger window, 0.5 to 1, and it works fine

Comment: @scoa Oh now I realized. Actually, I look for row values which is ==0.5 or closer to >=0.5&<=0.55 . Now the code you provide finds a row when all columns satisfies that condition.

Comment: you mean the sum of all values in X1:X5 should be in this interval?

Comment: @scoa not the sum. The row values. For example lets say when X1=0.52, X2=0.39, X3=0.56, X4=0.44, X5=0.52, your code doesnt provide this ouput. Only when all conditions are satisfied. I want to see even some columns doesnT show >=0.5 but other columns does.

Comment: so keep every row that has at least one value in X1:X5 in the interval? Then : `df%>% filter(rowSums(.[,names(.) %in% paste0("X",1:5)] >= 0.50 & .[,names(.) %in% paste0("X",1:5)] <= 0.55) > 0)`

Comment: @scoa it perfectly works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt the solution presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28184811/4132844). It looks for rows where at least one of the value responds to the condition (since logical vectors can be summed).

```
filter(df,rowSums(.[,names(.) %in% paste0("X",1:5)] >= 0.50 & .[,names(.) %in% paste0("X",1:5)] <= 0.55) > 0)
```