# How to filter rows for every column independently using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following tibble:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~gene, ~colB, ~colC,
  "a",   1,  2,
  "b",   2,  3,
  "c",   3,  4,
  "d",   1,  1
)

df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>    gene  colB  colC
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     a     1     2
#> 2     b     2     3
#> 3     c     3     4
#> 4     d     1     1
```

What I want to do is to filter every columns after `gene` column
for values greater or equal 2 (>=2). Resulting in this:

```r
gene, colB, colC
a   NA   2
b   2    3
c   3    4
```

How can I achieve that?

The number of columns after genes actually is more than just 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter each column of a data.frame based on a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183653/filter-each-column-of-a-data-frame-based-on-a-specific-value)

Comment: I guess you want `>= 2` since values of 2 appear in the desired output.

Comment: @neilfws: you're right. I updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution: convert from wide to long format, so you can filter on just one column, then convert back to wide at the end if required. Note that this will drop genes where no values meet the condition.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
gather(name, value, -gene) %>% 
  filter(value >= 2) %>% 
  spread(name, value)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
   gene  colB  colC
* <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1     a    NA     2
2     b     2     3
3     c     3     4
```

Answer (score 5):

The forthcoming dplyr 0.6 (install from GitHub now, if you like) has `filter_at`, which can be used to filter to any rows that have a value greater than or equal to 2, and then `na_if` can be applied similarly through `mutate_at`, so

```r
df %>% 
    filter_at(vars(-gene), any_vars(. >= 2)) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(-gene), funs(na_if(., . < 2)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>    gene  colB  colC
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     a    NA     2
#> 2     b     2     3
#> 3     c     3     4
```

or similarly,

```r
df %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(-gene), funs(na_if(., . < 2))) %>% 
    filter_at(vars(-gene), any_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

which can be translated for use with dplyr 0.5:

```r
df %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(-gene), funs(na_if(., . < 2))) %>% 
    filter(rowSums(is.na(.)) < (ncol(.) - 1))
```

All return the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD, `>=`, 2)), .SDcols = colB:colC]
   ][, (2:3) := lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x < 2, NA)), .SDcols = colB:colC][]
#   gene colB colC
#1:    a   NA    2
#2:    b    2    3
#3:    c    3    4
```

---

Or with `melt/dcast`

```
dcast(melt(setDT(df), id.var = 'gene')[value>=2], gene ~variable)
#   gene colB colC
#1:    a   NA    2
#2:    b    2    3
#3:    c    3    4
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively we could also try the below code

```r
df %>% rowwise %>% 
filter(any(c_across(starts_with('col'))>=2)) %>% 
mutate(across(starts_with('col'), ~ifelse(!(.>=2), NA, .)))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Rowwise: 
  gene   colB  colC
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a        NA     2
2 b         2     3
3 c         3     4
```