# How to filter rows for every column

Tags: r, filter, tidyverse

I have a big dataframe ( [data.txt](https://www.transfernow.net/SOvuuh042020)). The first column is the name of the genes, and the others column the Sample. An example of this df:

[image]

I followed up this post:

[How to filter rows for every column independently using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44233337/how-to-filter-rows-for-every-column-independently-using-dplyr)

Because is exactly what I am looking for. I want to create 3 subsets depending of the gene value. One subset for values: <0, ==0, and >0.

But I get this error:

```
Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys. Keys are shared for 448    rows: * 45317, 50187 * 64477, 65535 * 146028, 148040
```

I have used this code:

```
Data <- read.table("data_CNA.txt",sep="\t", header=TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
gain <- Data %>% gather(name, value, -Hugo_Symbol) %>% filter(value >= 1) %>% spread(name, value)
```

If you have any other idea better than this, is welcome!
Thanks

Comment: Yes because I have 5 posible values: -2, -1, 0, 1,  2. So we can say loss<- -2,-1. neutral<- ==0. gain<- 1,2

Comment: The error is from `spread` function do you have multiple columns with the same name or multiple rows with the same "Hugo_Symbol"?

Comment: @WindSur I managed to get the [data](https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/c3m9y43rpp/1/files/de2ebd9e-6011-48d0-8024-35d3a318f95c) . I found one variable named "Entrez_Gene_Id", which is an Id field and you are not using it. Not sure about the reason. However, to use gather and spread, you need **Id** field that uniquely identifies each row. And as you don't have it in your data set, spread is throwing you the error stating the same. i have modified my answer to incorporate Id field to your data frame.

Comment: I've just update with the data file. @Dave2e it should not have any duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create subsets based on column value, you can **create a temp_field based on gene values: <0, ==0, and >0**. and then **split** the data frame **using split function** of base library.

```
df_list <- Data %>% rownames_to_column(var = "Id") %>% 
  gather(name, value, -c(Hugo_Symbol,Id)) %>%
  mutate(temp_field = case_when(value < 0 ~ "loss",
                                value > 0 ~ "gain",
                                T ~ "neutral"),
         temp_field = as.factor(temp_field)
  ) %>% split(., .$temp_field)

spread_df_func <- function(df){
  d <- df %>% select(Id,Hugo_Symbol, name, value) %>% spread(key = name, value = value)
  return(d)
}

org_df_list <- df_list %>% map(spread_df_func)
```

As I don't have data to test, the above function may have syntactical error, however, it should be logically correct.

Let me know, if it solves your issue.

You may also refer to [link](http://dwoll.de/rexrepos/posts/dfSplitMerge.html), on split and merge data frame.

Comment: It works, but I do not know why I obtain different lenght columns. If I have 1071 varaibles in data, for neutral, gain and loss I have 1072,1059,1060, respectively. In neutral make senses because you add the Id column, but for the others I don not know.

Comment: @WindSur As we have written conditions on value, some fields might not be satisfying the condition. For eg: if the variable only has value less than 0, then it will appear in only in **loss** data frame, and it won't be available in other two data frame.